# Try - Catch Laravel on Index function

Tags: php, laravel, try-catch

***Hi everyone***

I've a question, and it's about Try - Catch, I've a function where I've 3 variables, from two differents models. The problem is, when the model don't have any records in DB, I try redirect the user from the home page, but dind't work, !important, one function had a request for an ajax function inside the view; here my code:

This one is with Try and Catch

> 

```
try
      {
        $events = Event::all();
        $competitions = Competition::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        $ultimos = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return Response::json(\View::make('events.partials.last', array('ultimos' => $ultimos))->render());
        }

        return View('events.index', compact('events', 'ultimos', 'competitions'));
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
          return redirect('/')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
      }
```

I used also and IF and ELSE, like this one:

> 

```
public function show_events(Request $request)
    {
      $events = Event::all();
      if($events) {  
        $competitions = Competition::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        $ultimos = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return Response::json(\View::make('events.partials.last', array('ultimos' => $ultimos))->render());
        }

        return View('events.index', compact('events', 'ultimos', 'competitions'));

      } else {
        return redirect('/')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
      }
    }
```

But didn't work to, if someone can help me, I'll be really gratefull!

Comment: I think Event::all() returns a Collection. It might be empty...but it's still a collection and thus not null...so your else won't run. You should probably check to see if the collection has items  like $events->count() > 0

Comment: You could use if(count($events)>0) instead of if($events) . then your else contion will work.

Comment: Thanks man, that's work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count` method of the collections like this :

```
public function show_events(Request $request)
    {
      $events = Event::all();
      if($events->count() > 0) {  
        $competitions = Competition::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
        $ultimos = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return Response::json(\View::make('events.partials.last', array('ultimos' => $ultimos))->render());
        }

        return View('events.index', compact('events', 'ultimos', 'competitions'));

      } else {
        return redirect('/')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
      }
    }
```

For the `try catch` it will not work because there no exception to catch here except if you throw one using the `count` method one more time like this

```
try {
    $events = Event::all();
    if($events->count() > 0) {  
        throw new Exception("Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos"); 
    }
    $competitions = Competition::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    $ultimos = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(5);

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return Response::json(\View::make('events.partials.last', array('ultimos' => $ultimos))->render());
    }

    return View('events.index', compact('events', 'ultimos', 'competitions'));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return redirect('/')->with('errors', 'Ha ocurrido un errror, lo sentimos');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use if(count($events)>0) instead of if($events) . then your else contion will work.